# Struts 2.0 action method called without actually invoking

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2

Found a strange issue in Struts action,
The scenario is like below ,

When I was in employees.jsp which just shows list of employees fetched from server , when an employee div is clicked, I will create a dynamic form as "employeeDetailsForm" in a javascript method, which has a hidden input field that holds value of employee code,

And I attached an action to the form as "getEmployeeDetails", when an employee div is clicked
It will submit the action and navigates to the employeeDetails.jsp,

In employeeDetails.jsp I will show set of details of that particular employee.
for his list of achievements I have upVote feature.
so when I click on upVote, upVote action gets called using ajax in a js method.
When upVote action is success , immediately again "getEmployeeDetails" action is getting called which is a strange behaviour.

I am not able to backtrace the call stack since many system defined methods are shown,

I just cross checked whether my "employeeDetailsForm" is exist in second jsp page as well and some how the form is being submitted somewhere ?

but when I checked inspector in browser, that form element was not there at all,
I also checked by calling `document.getElementById("employeeDetailsFormId")` which returned null

Then from where this method is getting called ?

How to trace this issue ?

Update -
Source code for reference

in employees.jsp - JS method to submit form to fetch details

```
var empDetForm = document.createElement("form");
empDetForm.id=“empDetailsId”;
empDetForm.name=“employeeDetailsForm";
empDetForm.method="POST";
empDetForm.action="getEmployeeDetails";

var empCodeinput = document.createElement("input");
empCodeinput.setAttribute("type","hidden");
empCodeinput.id= empCode;
empCodeinput.name=“empCode”;

empDetForm.appendChild(empCodeinput);

empDetForm.submit();
```

In employeeDetails.jsp - JS method to call upvote service using ajax

```
var formdata = "isUpVote="+isUpVote+”&”+”selectedAchievement="+achievementId;
    $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',      
              url: ‘achievementUpVote’,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
              async: false,
              //processData:false,
              data :formdata, 
              mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
              cache: false,
              processData:false,
              datatype: "json",
              success: function(response) {
                  alert("success upvote for achievement”);
              },
              error: function(e) { 
                  alert("Fail upvote");
              }
        });
```

Java struts action methods

```
public String getEmployeeDetails() throws JSONException {

        EmployeeDetailsIntf empDetailsImplObj = new EmployeeDetailsIml();
        JSONObject jsonInput = new JSONObject();

        String userName = ApplicationData.getUserName();
        String accessCode = ApplicationData.getAccessCode();

        jsonInput.put(“empId”, getEmpId());
        jsonInput.put("un", userName);
        jsonInput.put("ac", accessCode);

        status = empDetailsImplObj.callGetEmpDetailsService(jsonInput);

        if(status == true){
            return "SUCCESS";
        }
        return "FAIL";
    }
```

Another action

```
public String achievementRating() {
        String userName =   ApplicationData.getUserName();
        String accessCode = ApplicationData.getAccessCode();
        JSONObject jsonInputData = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonInputData.put("un", userName);
            jsonInputData.put("ac", accessCode);
            jsonInputData.put("aid", selectedAchivement);

            EmployeeDetailsIntf empDetailsImplObj = new EmployeeDetailsIml();

            boolean status = empDetailsImplObj.upVoteAchievement(jsonInputData, isUpVote);
            if (status) {
                return "RATE_ACHIEVEMENT_SUCCESS";
            }else{
                return "FAIL";
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null ; 

    }
```

struts.xml

```
<action name=“getEmployeeDetails” class="com.action.EmployeeDetailsAction"
    method="getEmployeeDetails">
    <result name="SUCCESS”>../empDetails/employeeDetails.jsp</result>
    <result name="FAIL">failure.jsp</result>
</action>
<action name="achievementUpVote" class="com.action.EmployeeDetailsAction"
    method="achievementRating">
    <result name="RATE_ACHIEVEMENT_SUCCESS" type="json"/>
    <result name="FAIL" type="json"/>
    <result name="FAIL">failure.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Consider adding relative code.

Comment: Consider migrating to 2.3.16.3

Comment: @AndreaLigios I am using struts 2.3.4.1 version, let me know do I need to update ? is there any issue in 2.3.4.1 version ?

Comment: The title of your question starts with "**Struts 2.0**" ... btw yes, all the versions older than 2.3.15.3 [are affected by security issues](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/s2-018.html). Migrate to 2.3.15.3 or higher (currently 2.3.16.3 is the latest) for a succesfull living :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios Even version 2.3.15.3 has security issues.  2.3.16.3 is the advisable version.  Besides that, the form does not exist in the DOM of the page.  It is created 'dynamically' when needed.  That is why you do not find it.

Comment: @tom form is not needed , I cross checked whether the action is getting called because of that form ? but it was not there which is an expected one. but how the action method is getting called ?

Comment: @Sadanand : ´empDetForm.submit();´  This little piece of javascript is calling the action (I think).  Try removing it and checking if it still gets called.

Comment: @tom that should call, that will happen in the first jsp file, but when I call upvote related action in second page, this first action is getting called again ( even though that form is no more exist )

Comment: @tom: the biggest security problems are resolved in 2.3.15.3. The remaining problems are not that much dangerous... btw, if your read my first commment, I'm "advising" 2.3.16.3... so what ? :)

Comment: @tom am using struts 2.3.4.1 still the same issue.
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts/struts2-core/2.3.4.1